# Calling a js.ThisFunction elegantly from Scala.js

Tags: scala, scala.js

The **`TypeScript`** definition for [mapbox-gl-js](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/) specifies that the **`loaded`** method of the **`Map`** class  return a **`boolean`**

```
loaded():boolean     //def loaded:Boolean = js.native in Scala.js
```

However, the method actually returns the following JavaScript function, which in turn returns the **`boolean`** expected.

```
function(){
  return !this._styleDirty&&!this._sourcesDirty&&!!this.style&&this.style.loaded()
}
```

This made me changed its return type to **`js.ThisFunction`**,

```
def loaded: js.ThisFunction = js.native
```

,called it with the current instance of the **`Map`** class named **`map`**, and then converted the resulting **`js.Dynamic`** to **`Boolean`**,

```
map.loaded.call(map).asInstanceOf[Boolean] //Passing in map as the execution context (this)
```

It works, albeit quite cumbersome. Any way to do it elegantly? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of the implementation, I would recommend to define the method as

```scala
def loaded(): Boolean = js.native
```

to begin with. Then you can call it as

```scala
map.loaded()
```

If you really want to make the `ThisFunction` explicit, you should at least use a typed one:

```scala
def loaded: js.ThisFunction0[Map, Boolean] = js.native
```

and then you can call it as

```scala
map.loaded(map)
```

Comment: @srjd Thanks! Everything turned out good with parentheses included (**`loaded()`** instead of **`loaded`**). I just wonder why?

Comment: Because without `()` the member defines a *property*, not a *method*, which in JS is accessed as `x.loaded` but not `x.loaded()`. Those are two different things in JS.